# Model Fails To Load

Tags: codeigniter

I am having issues with my Code Ignitor, in that I load my model the code fails, without leaving any trace.

I am attempting to load my model like so

```
<!--CONTROLLER-->
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Concierge extends Public_Controller {

public function submit()
{
    $this->load->model('Concierge_model');
}
```

My model is set up as below:

```
<!--MODEL-->
<?php

class Concierge_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

function saveRequest($action, $owner)
{
    $query = $this->db->query('select * from table');
    return $query;
}
```

Does anyone see what might be the issue that is causing my problem? I am using CodeIgnitor 2.1.2.

Comment: is your model saved as "conceirge_model.php"?  Also, try "extends CI_Controller" in your controller rather than public_controller.

Comment: @ICouldBeWrong Yes it is titled `concierge_model.php and changing to `CI_Controller` didn't fixed the problem, nor appear to make it worse.

Comment: try loading it in all lowercase `$this->load->model('concierge_model');`

Comment: @Jeesmusu, that's not how to properly call a model.  In CI, models are always first letter capital, rest lowercase, and file names are always lowercase.

Comment: @jeremy1026, Maybe try to create a construct in your controller while extending CI_Controller?  Also, if you're deploying via Git, make sure that git isn't adding files with other names (concierge_model.php && Conceirge_model.php) if you've deleted / renamed files.

Comment: @I Could Be Wrong , you appear to be correct. Although I've always loaded mine all lowercase and never had a problem.

Comment: Is it definitely the `$this->load->model('Concierge_model');` thats causing the problem? Try loading an empty model (remove all it's methods). If it loads it's probably some kind of parse/syntax error in your models code.

Comment: @ICouldBeWrong - you can do $this->load->model('model') in lower case - I always do this and it works 100%

Comment: @Jeremy1026 - what happens if you do something like 'echo "x";' instead of loading the model - do you see the 'x'? i.e. are you 100% sure it is the model causing the error?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I can do that on my local machine, but not on my ubuntu EC2 server.  It's weird but sometimes it's case sensitive and sometimes it's not.  So, I completely trust you but if you ever run into a model-loading problem when you load it onto a new site, just know that the lowercase might be it.

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Echoing information, setting data, doing anything else I can do in my controller. So I am definitely linking it to the model. If I echo x, load the model, and then echo y. I will get x outputted, then nothing else.

Comment: can you load another model? try making an 'empty' basic model - does that load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the problem was, I deleted the model, view, and controller and recreated them. This fixed the issue, but sadly didn't shed any light onto what caused it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Public_Controller is something custom, make sure that class extends CI_Controller and also make sure the parent's contruct function is called there.

```
class Public_Controller extends CI_Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
  }
}
```